# Trying to handle an exception two time in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to handle an exception 2 times

The first is in the core of a defined method :

```
Class Class1 {
    public int method (int a, String b) {
    try {
        System.out.println(a+"  "+b.length());
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("catch from the method");
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("finally from the method");
    }   
    return 0;
    }
}
```

and the second

is when I call this method in main and passing a null parameter to it :

```
public Class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Class1 c = null;
        try {
            c = new Class1();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            c.method(1, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("catch from the main");
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("finally from the main");
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnd of the main");
    }
}
```

and the result is :

> catch from the method
>
> finally from the method
>
> finally from the main
>
> End of the main

And now my question is, why the catch block in the main was not executed?

Comment: Because you are catching NullPointerException and not throwing any exception hence nothing to be catched by main method's catch block.

Comment: Because `public int method` in C class doesn't throw any exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you catch an Exception, it doesn't go any further, but you can throw it again.  If you want your main to also see the exception you need to throw the exception again after it is caught.  Try this:

```
 public int method (int a, String b) throws NullPointerException{
        try {
            System.out.println(a+"  "+b.length());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("catch from the method");
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("finally from the method");
        }   
        return 0;
        }
```

Notice since there is a throw in the function now, you need to include it in the function definition

Edit: As stated by a couple of people, NullPointerException does not really need to be caught because it is an unchecked exception.  This is because it is a subclass of RuntimeException.

Comment: Wow great answer ! But you can throw e without including it to the function definition

Comment: @user9152856 Just a note: NPE is an unchecked exception, which means it is bad practice to catch it

Comment: Only valid for NPE.

Answer (score 1):

You find many texts on the mechanics of throwing and catching exceptions. What I find more important is how to make best use of the exceptions concept.

This is not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe clarifies some concepts behind the situation at hand.

### Rules of Thumb

1. If a method fulfilled its job, it should return normally. If it failed to do so, it should throw an exception instead of the normal return. The exception coming out of your method should contain information on the problem (most of the standard exceptions already do that quite well).
2. In a subordinate method, you normally shouldn't use try/catch. If something goes wrong (some exception arises inside your method), then your method typically can't complete its job, it should tell its caller by means of an exception, and the easiest way is to just let the exception ripple through.
3. In a top-level method (e.g. main, main-menu action, button-click action), catch all exceptions, inform the user (and maybe the administrator) and continue (if possible/appropriate).
4. If your method gets one exception (e.g. a NullPointerException) and wants to show a different one to its caller, catch the exception, create the desired new one, using the original one as `cause`, and throw this new exception. Personally, I try to avoid this "exceptions translation" as much as possible.
5. Use `finally` if you have to close some resource that you obtained inside the body, that would stay blocked for extended periods of time if not closed. Think of I/O streams, database connections/transactions and similar things. Don't do it just for memory allocation, that's the garbage collector's job.

If you follow these rules, you'll find that your code can concentrate on its main job, isn't cluttered with lots of error handling, and still is robust in case of exceptions.

### Your Example

It all depends on the question "What's the job of `Class1.method()`?".

That might be "Print these two numbers". Then, when it gets the `NullPointerException`, it won't fulfill its job, so it shouldn't return normally, and instead exit with an exception, most easily by doing nothing (no try/catch at all) and just letting the exceptions framework do its automatic job. That will mean that its caller gets the original `NullPointerException`:

```
public int method (int a, String b) {
    System.out.println(a+"  "+b.length());
}
```

If the job of `Class1.method()` were "Print these two numbers, but only if there is a string", then you should catch the NullPointerException inside (or better, check with an `if`) and return normally ("I've done my job!"). Then `Class2.main()` should be satisfied with the non-printing in case of null, and have no reason to do any error handling after calling `Class1.method()`. If `Class2.main()` doesn't want that behaviour, it shouldn't call `Class1.method()` in that case.